# How to convert YOLOv5 PyTorch model to OpenCV DNN compatible format

Tags: opencv, onnx, yolov5, roboflow

Could anybody please help me to convert YOLOv5 PyTorch model to ONNX or TensorFlow format to be able to use it with OpenCV C++ inference?

I used this tutorial to train the model with colab: https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov5-on-a-custom-dataset/

Maybe there is a way of conversion in colab or I should use any other tools?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the recent reply from ultralytics developers(YoloV5 creators) regarding OpenCV & YoloV5 compatibility. In fact I'm also looking for correct implementation tutorial.

[Original Thread](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/239)

> Good news ! Your original issue may now be fixed ✅ in PR [#4833](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/pull/4833)
> by @SamFC10. This PR implements architecture updates to allow for
> ONNX-exported YOLOv5 models to be used with OpenCV DNN.
>
> To receive this update:
>
> - [Git](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) – `git pull` from within `your yolov5/` directory or `git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5`
> - [PyTorch Hub](https://pytorch.org/hub/ultralytics_yolov5/) – Force-reload with `model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', force_reload=True)`
> - [Notebooks](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/tutorial.ipynb) – View updated notebooks Open In Colab Open In Kaggle. [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/tutorial.ipynb)
> - [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/ultralytics/yolov5) – `sudo docker pull ultralytics/yolov5:latest` to update your image.
>
> Thank you for spotting this issue and informing us of the problem.
> Please let us know if this update resolves the issue for you, and feel
> free to inform us of any other issues you discover or feature requests
> that come to mind. Happy trainings with YOLOv5 !

Answer (score 1):

pt model to onnx that is able to be read by OpenCV 4.5.4 is as follows:

python3 export.py --weights best.pt --include onnx --simplify

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Google Colab where you don't have to worry about downloading huge chunks of data and fixing dependencies. You can use [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Object-Detection-using-YOLOv5-and-OpenCV-DNN-in-CPP-and-Python/Convert_PyTorch_models.ipynb) for converting models.

You can also check out this LearnOpenCV [blog post](https://learnopencv.com/object-detection-using-yolov5-and-opencv-dnn-in-c-and-python/) for more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).